# JavaScript critical error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am unable to include any javascript file in either the _Layout.cshtml or any other view. When I do so, I get the error "javascript critical error at line 3...". I'm using IE to browse. Errors are not shown in Chrome though. I am including the js file at the bottom of the view like this:

```
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The error is not specific to this file, any js file gives the error. I also tried sing the url.content, no luck. Thanks

Comment: Your script line is almost certainly a red herring.  The problem lies elsewhere, probably in some other Javascript you have at the top of the page.

Comment: If I comment out this line, there's no error at all. This is the first time I'm including a separate js file. The only ones that are already included are the bundles.

Comment: The `bootstrap.min.js` file is demonstrably good (since you said that it doesn't matter which library you include), so you're either including it wrong (which can be easily remedied by finding some known good examples on the Internet), or the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems quite unrelated to ASP.NET since you are including a static JS file, so it's pure HTML.

I suppose in this case you should remove the tilda character `~` from file URL.

Comment: Tried that too. It didn't help.

Comment: looks like images don't get displayed too. It looks somthing fundamental that I'm missing.